# Escribir un txt en python me da un error

Tags: python-3.x

Hola a todos hice el siguiente codigo en python 3.x

```
#Usando el archivo Names.txt que creó anteriormente, muestre la lista de nombres en Python. 
# Pídale al usuario que escriba uno de los nombres y luego guarde todos los nombres excepto el 
# que ingresó en un nuevo archivo llamado Names2.txt.
archivo = open("Nombres.txt","r")
print(archivo.read())
archivo.close()
nombre = input("Escribe un nombre del archivo que desee borrar:")
nombre = nombre + "\n"

for fila in archivo:
    if fila != nombre:
        archivo = open("Nombres2.txt","w")
        grabadon = fila
        archivo.write(grabadon)
        archivo.close()
archivo.close()
```

lo cual me genera el siguiente error tanto en visual estudio como en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es al escribir cuando tienes el error, es al intentar leer en `for fila in archivo:`, el error se debe a que has cerrado `archivo` en la línea 3 después del `print`.

Aún eliminando la llamada a `close` no funcionaría, al usar `read()` el puntero del descriptor está situado al final del archivo, por lo que el ciclo `for` no obtendrá ninguna línea del mismo. Debes posicionar el cursor al inico del fichero de nuevo o almacenar las líneas en una lista para reutilizarlas en el `for in`.

Por otro lado dentro del `for` usas la misma variable para asociar el archivo de salida (`archivo`) que la que usas para asociar el de entrada, por lo que invalidas el iterador sobre el primer archivo y terminas intentando leer sobre un archivo abierto en modo escritura.

Por último, abres y cierras el archivo de salida en cada iteración el ciclo, esto hace que en cada una de ellas trunques su contenido y al final solo contendrá una línea. Debes abrirlo fuera del ciclo o usar el modo `"a"` en todo caso.

Unas observaciones más, que aunque no son errores realmente deberías considerar:

- Aunque añades `\n` a la cadena ingresada para comparar de forma correcta, debes tener cuidado y asegurarte de que al escribir en el archivo usas siempre `\n`. En Windows por ejemplo se usa `\r\n`. Es recomendable usar `str.strip` / `str.rstrip` para eliminar los saltos de línea [independientemente del formato que se use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`, etc)
- De forma similar a lo anterior, tampoco es mala idea especificar la codificación a usar en `open`. Si no se especifica, usa la codificación local por defecto, que suele ser UTF-8 en *nix y CP1252 en Windows.
- Considera usar `with` (para usar el administrador de contexto) en vez de llamar a `close`, la ventaja es que cierra el archivo incluso si hay una excepción que ocasione la terminación inmediata de la ejecución.

---

```
with open("Nombres.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as archivo_entrada:
    print(archivo_entrada.read())
    archivo_entrada.seek(0)
    nombre = input("Escribe un nombre del archivo que desee borrar:")
    with open("Nombres2.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as archivo_salida:
        for fila in archivo_entrada:
            if fila.rstrip() != nombre:
                archivo_salida.write(fila)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estoy aprendiendo de un libro y me gustaría mas saber si esta mal planteada la solución que básicamente es esta:
file = open("Name.txt","r")
print(file.read())
file.close()

file = open("Name.txt","r")
selectedname  = input("Enter the name:")
selectedname = selectedname +"\n"
for row in file:
    if row != selectedname:
        file  = open("Name2.txt","a")
        newrecord = row
        file.write(newrecord)
        file.close()
file.close()

Comment: Que libro en español puedes recomendarme te lo agradeceria bastante y muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, el libro que utilizo se llama:PYTHON BY EXAMPLE
Learning to Program in 150 Challenges
by NICHOLA LACEY

Comment: En esa solución se opta por cerrar y volver a abrir el archivo en vez de mover el cursor, es algo menos eficiente, pero es una solución, Por otro lado se usa el modo "a" como ya comentaba en mi respuesta, tiene como ventaja (o no) que si el archivo de salida va a ser un archivo vacío (no se cae en el if) no se crea, como desventaja tiene que abrimos y cerramos el archivo por cada linea, lo cual no es muy eficiente que digamos.

Comment: En Español gratuito puedes mirate: los enlaces que hay en la etiqueta https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info, el nivel de actualización es otra cosa. La verdad es que no estoy muy actualizado en cuanto a  libros  ahora mismo, los que he tocado recientemente son de temas muy específicos (Tensorflow, OpenCv, etc), Para Python estándar simplemente uso la documentación para ir actualizandome...